# Return False Not Applicable in All Fields

Tags: jquery

I was surprised by this string. To 4 fields can control the return false but some field below is not working. Though the code I use the exact same.

I have tried several times to change the composition and still fail
What is the cause of this failure?

The following code

```js
$('#button_small').click(function(){
  var error = false;
var logowarning = '<img class="img-reg" src="warning.gif" alt=" !"/>';
  if ($('#username').val()=='') {
 $('.username').html(logowarning)
  error = true;
 }

  if ($('#password').val()=='') {
 $('.password').html(logowarning)
  error = true;
 }

  if ($('#passverif').val()=='') {
 $('.passverif').html(logowarning)
  error = true;
 }

  if ($('#email').val()=='') {
 $('.email').html(logowarning)
  error = true;
 }

  if ($('#provinsi').val()=='') {
 $('.provinsi').html(logowarning)
  error = true;
 }

  if ($('#kota').val()=='') {
 $('.kota').html(logowarning)
  error = true;
 }
 
 return !error;
})

$('#username').click(function(){
$('.username').html('')
})

$('#password').click(function(){
$('.password').html('')
})

$('#passverif').click(function(){
$('.passverif').html('')
})

$('#email').click(function(){
$('.email').html('')
})

$('#provinsi').click(function(){
$('.provinsi').html('')
})

$('#kota').click(function(){
$('.kota').html('')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <form id='id_form' action='signup.php' method='post'>
 
<label for='password'>Password1:</label>
<input type='password' id='password' name='password' /><span class='password'></span><br />

<label for='passverif'>Password2:</label>
<input type='password' id='passverif' name='passverif' /><span class='passverif'></span><br /><br /> 
 
<label for='username'>Name:</label>
<input type='text' id='username' name='username'/><span class='username'></span><br />

<label for='email'>E-mail:</label>
<input type='text' id='email' name='email'/><span class='email'></span><br /><br />

<label for='Provinsi'>Provinsi:</label>
<input id='Provinsi' type='text' name='provinsi'/><span class='provinsi'></span><br />

<label for='Kota'>Kota:</label>
<input id='Kota' type='text' name='kota'/><span class='kota'></span><br /><br />

<label for='NoHP'>Phone:</label>
<input onKeyPress="return kodeScript(event,'0123456789',this)" type='text' id='NoHP' name='ponsel'/><br /><br />
   
<label style='width:auto' for='area_register'>Nama Jalan / Alamat Tambahan:</label><br />
<textarea style='width: 400px !important; height: 80px !important;border-color: #D03102;' spellcheck='false' id='area_register' type='text' name='jalan'></textarea><br />
 
<input id='button_small' type='submit' value='Register' />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your HTML

```
<input id='Provinsi' type='text' name='provinsi'/><span class='provinsi'></span><br />
```

While in your jquery you are referencing it like

```
if ($('#provinsi').val()=='')
```

Your ID doesn't match. P should be capital in jquery or small in HTML. jQuery is case-sensitive